# How to add a class within raw filter marks?

Tags: php, twig, pinterest, kuma

In the Kuma CMS, our users create list items for instructions. There are titles and other text as well. Mostly h2, ul/li, and p elements.

It gets added to the page with `{{ resource.list|raw }}`

Is there a way to add a class to only LI tags within the `{{ resource.list|raw }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to [replace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html) the `<li>` tags:

```
{{ resource.list|replace({'<li>': '<li class="your-class">'})|raw }}
```

Working example: https://twigfiddle.com/svajsh

Comment: It looks like you're new here. Have a look here ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers